# Create Algolia connection to Neo4j graph database

Tags: node.js, graph, algolia

Can you use the Node.js Algolia API to create a connection to a graph database in Neo4j?

Comment: Algolia is a search engine; it searches in its own database that you feed it in. If you want to search through a Graph database you need a search engine for that database.

Comment: If you're able to export the graph nodes to a "flat" list, you can definitely use Algolia to index them.

Comment: I agree with @redox, excepts it defeats the purpose of using a Graph database in the first place.